# Error when trying to mock a DataFrameReader object when using ScalaMock

Tags: scala, mocking, scalamock

I want to test a method we have that is formatted something like this:

```
def extractTable( spark: SparkSession, /* unrelated other parameters */ ): DataFrame = {
  // Code before that I want to test
  val df = spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "URL")
    .option("driver", "<Driver>")
    .option("fetchsize", "1000")
    .option("dbtable", "select * from whatever")
    .load()
  // Code after that I want to test 
}
```

And I am trying to make stubs of the spark object, and the DataFrameReader objects that the `read` and `option` methods return:

```
val sparkStub = stub[ SparkSession ]
val dataFrameReaderStub = stub[ DataFrameReader ]

( dataFrameReaderStub.format _).when(*).returning( dataFrameReaderStub ) // Works
( dataFrameReaderStub.option _).when(*, *).returning( dataFrameReaderStub ) // Error
( dataFrameReaderStub.load _).when(*).returning( ??? ) // Return a dataframe // Error

( sparkStub.read _).when().returning( dataFrameReaderStub )
```

But I am getting an error on `dataFrameReaderStub.option` and `dataFrameReaderStub.load` that says "Cannot resolve symbol option" and "Cannot resolve symbol load". But these methods definitely exist on the object that `spark.read` returns.

How can I resolve this error, or is there a better way to mock/test the code I have?

Comment: Did you find a way to mock the methods?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at this library for testing Spark code: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base

Mix in this with your test suite: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/SharedSparkContext
...or alternatively, spin up your own SparkSession with a local[2] master. and load the test data from csv/parquet/json.

Mocking Spark classes will be quite painful and probably not a success. I am speaking from experience here, both working for a long time with Spark, and maintaining ScalaMock as a library.

You are better off using Spark in your tests, but not against the real datasources.
Instead, load the test data from csv/parquet/json, or programatically generate it (if it contains timestamps and such).

Comment: I don't disagree that scalaMock is lacking, but I am not really sure how that will help. I have a method that has a bunch of code before and after a spark.read command, and that is the code I want to test. For example, the code generates an oracle query that it uses to extract the data and then passes it to the spark.read, how can I inject my own spark.read in the middle of a method

Comment: you probably need a different way of abstracting in your code then, e.g. a layered mix-in (or DI injected) trait that you can replace in the test code